# Java Functions vs Spring Converter for data transformation

Tags: java, spring, lambda

I was looking at some code written a few months back and I stumbled across some service class that was doing the following:

1. Queries the db and acquires a list of entities (for convenience let's consider them `Person` entities).
2. Streams the queried list and converts the retrieved data over to a list of `PersonDto` transfer objects.

Now, for step #2 a custom Spring converter is used to perform the conversion from type A (`Person`) to type B (`PersonDto`).

Now my question is the following. The same exact operation can be performed using a similar `java.util.` function instead of the Spring converter. So what are the advantages of using that instead of the method?

I was looking at the docs and aside from the fact that any Spring converter implementation is mentioned to be thread-safe, I don't see any other noticeable differences.

I tend to use Spring converters a lot, since I am able to inject them in various places and re-use them but I suppose the same can be done with a service class containing self-executing lambda functions.

So as mentioned above what are the possible advantages/disadvantages of using Spring converters vs plain functions.

Comment: A third option, there's a Java library called MapStruct that is designed to eliminate the boilerplate of manually creating these converters: http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#defining-mapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There not might be any depending on your use case. The converter part was implemented back in Spring 3, with support for Java 5 (and 6), so `Function` wasn't there.

But importantly, the converter functionality is part of Spring. While you can easily call your functions, Spring doesn't understand anything about it. Spring does understand its own converters though, so you can write converters that will allow the whole Spring framework to understand how to convert `A` to `B`, where `A` is something that Spring doesn't understand and `B` is something it does. This may be required in some special cases, even though the most common use cases are already written for you.

So Spring's Converter functionality isn't mainly about transforming data, it's about extending the functionality of the Spring framework itself. Using it to convert data yourself manually is more of a side-effect than a real use case.

Comment: This is a good answer but still misses my original question. Since converters are now effectively functional interfaces I do not see the point why one may not use it for data transformation in various cases. I do understand that a converter can be used for other uses too (registering in the general context etc etc) but I am most interested in a usage comparison for such cases. My main question is technically wise, are there any differences?

Comment: @Aris you asked for the differences and I told them. No, there's no other major difference between `Function` and `Converter`, the interfaces are identical except for the default methods. Of course it's a lot easier to find implementors of `Converter` interface than find your converter functions, so if your project is using `Converter` already, there's no advantage for you to switch to `Function`.

Comment: I have a feeling you're looking for some deeper meaning in this completely irrelevant choice you seem to be making. Is it because you think `Function` is newer and therefore more advanced and "better"?

Comment: Indeed I am. I'm more inclined to see if there is any underlying technical implications between one approach and the other.

Comment: The actual technical implications were discussed in my answer, if you ignore those, there's no difference. You can assign the same lambda to a `Function` and `Converter`. No difference whatsoever which one you use.

Comment: I see. Fair enough. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you register `Converter<S,T>` to Spring container, Spring is capable of automatically convert value for you.

Comment: Does the converter is good to use?
I use it in entity on 3 fields.
Does this is bad when calling getAll()?